# Most efficient database date storing method?

Tags: php, sql, date, space-efficiency

So I am looking to store a date in my SQL database and am not sure what the most efficient way would be.  I have thought of two different methods.

Firstly, people are going to be able to set a certain price for each day.

For example:

> March 8, 2011: $1
>
> March 9, 2011: $2
>
> March 10, 2011: $5

For my database I was thinking of either storing a UNIX timestamp or storing in the month, day, and year in separate fields.

First method:

**UNIX Timestamp**

*Pros*

- Only one field

*Cons*

- Have to convert date to timestamp
- Have to search between start and end dates
- Prone to errors in search

**Month/Day/Year**

*Pros*

- Easier to search

*Cons*

- More fields
- Takes up more space
- Will be storing a LOT of data so could slow down the database.

With the above information, what would be your recommendation?  (I can clarify if any of this is not clear.)

Comment: Separate fields? What's wrong with the `DATE` type?

Comment: I am so tempted to down-vote (but I won't :-) just because of the amount of pure "optimization" (note the quotes). I would generally punch a co-worker for these "suggestions".

Comment: Please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html -- as you can see, DATE (3 bytes), DATETIME (8 bytes) and TIMESTAMP (not to SQL'spec, 4 bytes) cover all the "needs", depending upon what the business requirements are. I doubt that the extra 4 bytes of the DATETIME over a TIMESTAMP (and *DON'T use an integer*) would even be noticeable in aggressive benchmarks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

timestamp/datetime/date fields are more efficient (they are all stored as integers).
So search is **much** faster on that.
There is a small (very) overhead of the conversion between different date formats, but, unless you join by date fields (which is ...usually... not smart) you have no issue, it will happen only once.
I do not see how it is error prone.

Comment: I was saying error prone that like if I convert the dates incorrectly.  Also, what do you mean by join the date fields?

Comment: @Flipper they mean using a JOIN between tables in an query. A JOIN between tables using date fields is usually not smart.

Comment: Ah.  I don't use JOIN in the first place.  So in conclusion which will be more efficient then?  The timestamp stored as an integer or the DATE column given by SQL?

Comment: There is no problem with a join between datetime/timestamp/date fields. They are all common integrals [per-type] underneath (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) -- it is the human-text which is a conversion so unless there is a join with an incompatible (read: text) field -- no problem. But generally pick one "type" (the one that fits the model) and stick with it.

Comment: @pst -  I wouldn't mind you editing the answer. I meant what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `DATE` field, that's what they're for.

Comment: Yes, but are they efficient versus the integer storing?

Comment: @Flipper As much as you will ever notice -- yes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a DATETIME or DATE column type -- easy to search and just one column, and easy to search within a date range...